# why do all elements of the relocation table have an additional offset?

Tags: windows, dll, x86, portable-executable, relocation

The question is about loading portable executable images to a random address.

Let's take kernel32.dll as an example, loaded at 0x75A00000.

I can see that at offset 0x10e15 from the image, there is an assembler instruction, which depends on where the image is located.

address:
75A10E13
bytes:
8B 35 18 03 AE 75
command:
MOV ESI,DWORD PTR DS:[75AE0318]

It turns out that by launching the executable file, we must tell the system that we need to relocation to this address.

The system looks at the relocation table, which is in the executable file, and sees the following:
[base relocation table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Snn3s.png)

To get the absolute address of the first element to be moved, I do the following: add the virtual address to the address of the image, and then I add the first element of the block to the resulting number.

0x75A00000 + 0x10000 + 0x3E15 = 75A10E15

it's a good number, but always 0x3000 more than I expect. i just subtract 0x3000 and it works. Please, help me find the answer, where does 0x3000 for x86 come from?

Answer (score 7):

Relocation in *Portable Executables* were resolved when the file was linked. The [base relocation table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Snn3s.png), which you are referring, has a different function: it is used by Windows loader when the PE could not be loaded at the prefered *ImageBase* address specified by the linker, usually 0x0040_0000.
*Dynamically Loaded Libraries* shipped with MS Windows are linked to *ImageBase* addresses different for each core DLL and chosen not to colide with one another, so an executable which imports usual combination of libraries doesn't have to relocate them.

You misinterpreted the format of [base relocation section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format#the-reloc-section-image-only) **.reloc**.
Those 16bit words *TypeOrOffset* which follow *PageRVA* and *BlockSize* have their Base Relocation Type encoded in **four most significant bits**.
For instance the first *TypeOrOffset* entry in you dump 0x3E15 has type IMAGE_REL_BASED_HIGHLOW (3) and offset 0x0E15, which is the number to be added to PageRVA.